# Loop over first list in a list of lists/nested list - R

Tags: r, list, loops, nested-lists

I am new to R. I normally use Python. Let's say I have a list of 100 items. Each item is a list of 3 items. This is the data structure.

```
List > Companies > Date, Revenues, Expenses
```

I can retrieve information using:

```
list$companyA$revenue
```

I want to iterate through the 100 companies.

When I used this code, I end up getting everything printed:

```
for(i in 1:length(list)) {    
  print(list[i])             
}
```

I have also tried:

```
lapply(list, `[[`, 1)
```

This gives the 100 companies and the first list item, the date.

I want to put this information into a function:

```
Function(list$company[1])
```

And I want to iterate through each company, so I can automatically do

```
Function(list$companyA[1])
Function(list$companyB[1])
etc
```

I can't seem to find the right answer. Maybe I am searching for it in the wrong way.

EDIT: To be clear, I want a list of the companies, so I can iterate through the companies.

EDIT2: Here is an example data:

```
Company     Date         Revenues   Expenses
A           08012022     100        100
A           08022022     102        100
B           08012022     200        150
B           08012022     202        150
```

To get it into a list of lists, I used

```
list <- lapply(split(clean, clean$Company), as.list)
```

Now, from my understanding of Python, I want a list of my companies,so I can iterate through them and put them in a function:

```
firms = ("A, B")
```

So I can iterate through each company and replace it in the function.

My thought is then to have something like (again from Python):

```
for (firm in firms) {
Function(list$firm[2], list$firm[3])
}
```

Comment: No, I want to iterate through each company to eventually put certain elements in the function.

Comment: `lapply(list, \(x) Function(x[[1]]))`

Comment: Sorry, I guess I am not clear. Wanting the Date element was just an example. I don’t want to use the function that way literally. I want to be able to iterate through the companies. It looks like this incorporates Function, but I don’t want to do that.

Comment: I simply want a list of my companies, so I can iterate through them.

Comment: I think it'll be straight if you provide a minimal reproducible example data and your expected output.

Comment: See edit2 - I think that should make it better. Thanks.

Comment: So do you want to get `firms = c("A", "B")`? Then just use `names(list)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `names()` to extract the list names, and iterate them in the loop.

```r
firms <- names(list)

for (firm in firms) {
  Function(list[[firm]][2], list[[firm]][3])
}
```

Note that you cannot use `list$firm` in the for loop. The `$` works only if `list` has an element named `firm`. In the loop you should use `list[[firm]]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare R and Python...here you go.

I've put your data through `dput()`. You should do this or a `reprex` when you ask R questions. (You'll get answers faster.)

```
firm <- structure(list(Company = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), 
                       Date = structure(c(19000, 19031, 19000, 19000), 
                                        class = "Date"),
                       Revenues = c(100L, 102L, 200L, 202L), 
                       Expenses = c(100L, 100L, 150L, 150L)), 
                  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Now, because you were asking about lists, I converted this data frame to a list.

```
# make this data frame a list, by rows
frm2 <- split(firm, seq(nrow(firm)))
```

You can use a for statement the same way in R. This will print out the 1st and 2nd indices in each list. The double brackets let me keep the date formatting.
The variable `firms` does not need to exist before making this call.

```
for(firms in frm2){
  message(firms[1], ' ', firms[[2]])
}
A 2022-01-08
A 2022-02-08
B 2022-01-08
B 2022-01-08
```

Or see it all

```
for(firms in frm2){
  message("In the company, ", firms[1], ", you'll see that on ", 
          firms[[2]], " Revenue was $", firms[3],
          " & Expenses were $", firms[4])
}
# In the company, A, you'll see that on 2022-01-08 Revenue was $100 & Expenses were $100
# In the company, A, you'll see that on 2022-02-08 Revenue was $102 & Expenses were $100
# In the company, B, you'll see that on 2022-01-08 Revenue was $200 & Expenses were $150
# In the company, B, you'll see that on 2022-01-08 Revenue was $202 & Expenses were $150
```